# split() a String to a Stringarray, and not getting a blank at [0]

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, whitespace

I'm trying to split() a String with no whitespaces, but getting a blank at [0].

```
String s = "..1..3..";
String[] result2 = s.split("");
System.out.println(result2[0]); // giving me a blank space
```

I'v realized that "" might not be the right one, but cant find a alternative. Is it possible to split on something else, or will I always get this whitespace when using split() this way?

EDIT SOLUTION:

```
     StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
     while((i = in.read()) != -1){     
            response.append((char)i);  
     }
     result = response.toString();   
     result = result.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: Why are you trying to split it? Are you just looking for an array of the characters?

Comment: `String.toCharArray();`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `0` contains the data from the beginning of the string to the first dot (i.e. an empty string)
- `1` contains the first dot
- `2` contains the second dot
- `3` contains the string `1`
- ...

Comment: Actually, the last item in the array will be the final "."

Comment: @syb0rg Java Strings are not the same as C-style char arrays. There's definitely no (user-visible) \0 at the end of the string, even if that's how it's stored under the covers.

Comment: @syb0rg I don't think you can get the `\0` out of the String by using split... if you use String.length() and then iterate through all chars, you will not run across the terminating char.

Comment: @syb0rg I think thats a result of the split method freaking out.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex splits at every position in the input, including the first position, which is at the start of input - *before* the first character. The first element found then is what's between the start of input and the first character, which is of course a zero-length string - a blank.

However you don't need special code to handle this. To get every character in a `String` as `String[]`, you need to use this regex:

```
String[] chars = input.split("(?<=.)";
```

This regex is a *look behind* that means "after every character".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `charAt()` method to do what you did.

If you do it in your way, you may need to remove the first element of the returned array. One way to do this is using `Arrays.copyOfRange()`.

```
String[] newArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArr, 1, oldArr.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `String.toCharArray();` then cast that array to `String[]`  if you really need it to be String[] type, otherwise char[] looks to be exactly what you're trying to do, except you wont wind up with those funny empty strings in element 0 and 9.